# Disable opening app in app

Tags: file-management

When I am in the file browser and open a PDF, the PDF viewer will be shown as the file manager in the list of the apps. When I press back in the PDF viewer, it will go back to the file manager eventually.

Is there some way to make the app open on its own, with the given file as a starting point?

Comment: Not in stock Android: it's up to the app to say whether it is a new *task* or not. There might be a way to do it with a custom ROM, but there might be something different you can do instead. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This is the stack in android, the default is to open an activity of the PDF reader from the File Explorer. It's down to how the dev wants to handle it, but this is the usual way. You could start reading here if you're interested: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html there's a lot of information and it leads into multiple activities from multiple applications etc. As Dan said a custom ROM might do this, or scripts running over everything. This is the 'ususal' functioality but you could try ES File Manager or an alternative and see what they do!

Answer (score 2):

There is an Xposed module that does this, it's called [ActivityForceNewTask](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.germainz.activityforcenewtask).

Assuming you're rooted, install the Xposed Installer, install the framework from within the app, reboot, download the module, enable it, reboot again.